# Python Multithreaded Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am doing a project for the end of the semester and I need to be able to take a matrix to a power and I need to make the problem multithreaded.

This code works in some situations and does not in other situations. I believe that it has to do with the logic in the nested loops in the process_data function but I am not sure what I am doing wrong! I have been working on this for a couple weeks and I am absolutely stumped. It seems like it has something to do with my threads going out of bounds but even then I am not very sure because there are some situations where the threads go out of bounds but then still calculates the matrices properly.

Please help!

```
import copy
import numpy
import Queue
import random
import threading
import time
import timeit

# Create variable that determines the number of columns and
# rows in the matrix.
n = 4

# Create variable that determines the power we are taking the
# matrix to.
p = 2

# Create variable that determines the number of threads we are
# using.
t = 2

# Create an exit flag.
exitFlag = 0

# Create threading class.
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.q)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

# Create a function that will split our data into multiple threads
# and do the matrix multiplication.
def process_data(threadName, q):
    numCalc = ((n^3)/t)
    for a in range(p-1):
        for b in range((numCalc*(q-1)),(numCalc*(q))):
            for c in range(n):
                for d in range(n):
                    matrix[a+1][b][c] += matrix[a][b][d] * matrix[0][d][c]

# Create a three dimensional matrix that will store the ouput for
# each power of the matrix multiplication.
matrix = [[[0 for k in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(p)]
print matrix

# This part fills our initial n by n matrix with random numbers
# ranging from 0 to 9 and then prints it!
print "Populating Matrix!"
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n): 
        matrix[0][i][j] = random.randint(0,9)

# Tells the user that we are multiplying matrices and starts the
# timer.
print "Taking our matrix to the next level!"
start = timeit.default_timer()
threadLock = threading.Lock()

threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in range(t):
    thread = myThread(threadID, "Thread-0"+str(tName), threadID)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1
# Wait for all threads to complete
for x in threads:
    x.join()

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start 
print "Exiting main thread!"
print matrix
```

Taking the matrix squared seems to work in every case but if I try to calculate beyond that the remaining powers come out with matrices that are filled with zeroes! The case that I have posted works.

When I change the n, p and t variables is when I run into problems where it does not calculate properly.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you would be much further ahead to use `numpy` - internally it uses the BLAS library, which is highly optimized and can be compiled as multithreaded internally, far faster (probably literally three or more orders of magnitude faster) than anything you can do in raw Python.

Comment: What does `numCalc` do?

Comment: numCalc is supposed to determine the number of calculations each thread is supposed to do. I'm trying to use it to do start and end indices but my math is wrong in here somewhere I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

```
numCalc = ((n^3)/t)

  for b in range((numCalc*(q-1)),(numCalc*(q))):
```

For instance, when n = 4 and t = 2, the first thread should have b range over the columns [0,1] and the second thread range over the columns [2,3]. But this calculation gives:

```
numCalc = 8 / 2 = 4
thread 1 ranges b over range(0, 4) = [0,1,2,3]
thread 2 ranges b over range(4, 8) = [4,5,6,7]
```

So thread 1 does all of the work and thread 2 tries to access non-existent columns!

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks! I'll tinker with this and see if I can fix it. =)